# RichEditBox TextChangedEvent fired infinitely in UWP?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

what i have tried?
My Xmal Code:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid">
     <RichEditBox x:Name="richbox" TextChanged="RichEditBox_TextChanged" Width="300" Height="70"/>
</Grid>
```

My C# Code:

```
    static int count = 0;
    private void RichEditBox_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RichEditBox richEditBox=sender as RichEditBox;
        Debug.WriteLine("Count :  " + count++);

        // ITextCharacterFormat textCharacterFormat = richEditBox.Document.GetDefaultCharacterFormat();
        // textCharacterFormat.ForegroundColor = Colors.Blue;
        // richEditBox.Document.SetDefaultCharacterFormat(textCharacterFormat);
    }
```

when i'm tried to change the text in RichEditBox,the textChangedEvent has been fired only once for each change , if i comment the three lines which changes the textCharacterFormat.If the uncomment the three lines ,the textchanged event fired infinitely.

I Don't know ,Why this is happening and how can i change the TextCharacterFormat ForegroundColor in uwp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I Don't know ,Why this is happening and how can i change the TextCharacterFormat ForegroundColor in uwp?

The problem is [`SetDefaultCharacterFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.itextdocument.setdefaultcharacterformat?view=winrt-19041) method will trigger `TextChanged`, and you place `SetDefaultCharacterFormat` in the `TextChanged` event, it will make the event into infinite loop.

For your scenario, you could make a value to record previous value. if current value is different with previous value, then call `SetDefaultCharacterFormat` that could prevent infinite loop.

```
static int count = 0;
private string prevoius = string.Empty;
private void RichEditBox_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RichEditBox richEditBox = sender as RichEditBox;
    Debug.WriteLine("Count :  " + count++);

    var current = string.Empty;
    richEditBox.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.FormatRtf, out current);
    if (current.Length != prevoius.Length)
    {
        ITextCharacterFormat textCharacterFormat = richEditBox.Document.GetDefaultCharacterFormat();
        textCharacterFormat.ForegroundColor = Colors.Blue;
        richEditBox.Document.SetDefaultCharacterFormat(textCharacterFormat);
      
    }

    prevoius = current;
}
```

**Update**

> Is there any other way to change the color

you could make specific color button and call the following code to edit richbox's ForegroundColor.

```
richbox.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.ForegroundColor = Colors.Red;
```

Comment: yeah.it will work.But it affect the performance of the application because of continuous calling of the event.Is there any other way to change the color?